# What do I call a hit-and-run situation in Russian?

Tags: перевод

[Hit-and-run](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit_and_run_%28vehicular%29) is the act of causing (or contributing to) a traffic accident (such as colliding with a person or a fixture), and failing to stop and identify oneself afterwards.

Usage context:

> With personal injury or death, hit-and-run drivers of motor vehicles
>   are also subject to imprisonment of 6 months to 5 years

Comment: Just for the sake of completenes - Hit-and-Run is also a name of a military tactic, which is translated to Russian as "наскок-отход".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually one talks about *бегство с места ДТП* (= дорожно-транспортного происшествия). In a more formal style *оставление места ДТП* is also used.

Comment: Yes, but it worth to mention also that in case we should use a verb, it is more appropriate to say not "убежал с места происшествия" but "скрылся с места происшествия".

Answer (score 10):

The legalese for this would be *оставление места ДТП*.

> КоАП РФ, 12.27, п. 2
>
> Оставление водителем в нарушение Правил дорожного движения места дорожно-транспортного происшествия, участником которого он являлся, -
>
> влечет лишение права управления транспортными средствами на срок от одного года до полутора лет или административный арест на срок до пятнадцати суток.